# How to split / unpivot group_concat in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, group-concat

I currently have a view that has a column called alt_email_contact and I used the group_concat function in order to get multiple emails associated with one contact. However I want to be able to extract each email and create a separate column for each.

Example:

```
id    email
 1     SkyW@gmail.com, SW@gmail.com, WW@gmail.com, WalterW@gmail.com
```

the amount of emails is subject to change from one user to another therefore there wont always be four emails for each user. I want to create a new column per each email like so:

```
id      email_1         email_2        email_3        email_4 
1       SkyW@gmail.com  SW@gmail.com   WW@gmail.com   WalterW@gmail.com
```

(I am using phpmyadmin) I would like to be able to modify my view to contain the variable amount of emails per user.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What is wrong with having each alternate email in it's own row (i.e. no `group_concat` at all)? This is much more scalable than having `X` number of columns (with `X` not being known before initial query is made).

Comment: A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.  How many emails do you want?

Comment: @MikeBrant I am importing these fields to another database and in order to do that I have to map one field to another field. Therefore I need all emails associated with one contact to be in one row (and each email be in a separate column).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want 5 emails, there can be however less than 5

Comment: @dantheman  In the target database, why do you need these values all in one row?  What you are in essence trying to do is NOT what relational databases are meant to do.

Comment: @MikeBrant I know I am not trying to CREATE a relational db I am merely trying to acquire values that I will then import to another db (which is relational). The import works on one ID, so if multiple users have the same id (with different emails) it will only import one row, not both, and the emails (if more than one) will be indistinguishable.

Comment: @dantheman So there is some script involved here to do this import? Why don't you configure the script to work with properly normalized values?  Not trying to be difficult here, I just have no erthly idea why one would want to do what you are proposing from a data persistence perspective. For ding reporting or something like that, it is trivial to have  a script take normalized data and show in a denormalized way, but trying to propogate a denormalized data structure between relational databases doesn't seem to make any sense at all.

Comment: @dantheman I can't tamper with the script which is why I am trying to find a work-around. I understand your pov but I am opting for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()` to achieve what you want.  It is not really pretty, but it will work:

```
select id,
       substring_index(emails, ', ', 1) as email_1
       (case when length(emails) - length(replace(emails, ',', '')) >= 1
             then substring_index(substring_index(emails, ', ', 2), ', ', -1)
        end) as email_2,
       (case when length(emails) - length(replace(emails, ',', '')) >= 2
             then substring_index(substring_index(emails, ', ', 3), ', ', -1)
        end) as email_3,
       (case when length(emails) - length(replace(emails, ',', '')) >= 3
             then substring_index(substring_index(emails, ', ', 4), ', ', -1)
        end) as email_4,
       (case when length(emails) - length(replace(emails, ',', '')) >= 4
             then substring_index(substring_index(emails, ', ', 5), ', ', -1)
        end) as email_5     
from table t;
```

You can insert these values into another table, if you like.

Comment: @GordonLiff, when I try to implement this query, it gives me duplicates, so for example if a contact only has two emails it will display this: email_1: w@gmail.com, email_2:ww@gmail.com, email_3:ww@gmail.com, email_4: ww@gmail.com, email_5: ww@gmail.com. How can i fix this  ?

Comment: For each additional column of the output, you would need to nest the `substring_index()` calls more deeply.

Comment: i always need 5 columns.

Comment: @dantheman . . . There was an off-by-error in the `when` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that view, since `GROUP_CONCAT()` has already ruined the normalization.  You want to simulate a pivot table using the limited SQL capabilities of MySQL.

Let's assume that your view is based on a `Contacts` table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts
( id INTEGER NOT NULL
, alt_email_contact VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
```

Create this helper view instead (which is basically `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY alt_email_contact)`, except that MySQL doesn't support `RANK()`):

```
CREATE VIEW NumberedContacts AS
    SELECT c1.id, c1.alt_email_contact, COUNT(*) AS rank
        FROM Contacts c1
            INNER JOIN Contacts c2
                ON c2.id = c1.id AND
                   c1.alt_email_contact >= c2.alt_email_contact
        GROUP BY c1.id, c1.alt_email_contact;
```

Then you can write this query or view, which gives you up to 5 alternate e-mail addresses, ordered alphabetically:

```
CREATE VIEW ContactsForImport AS
    SELECT c1.id
         , c1.alt_email_contact AS email_1
         , c2.alt_email_contact AS email_2
         , c3.alt_email_contact AS email_3
         , c4.alt_email_contact AS email_4
         , c5.alt_email_contact AS email_5
        FROM NumberedContacts AS c1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN NumberedContacts AS c2
                ON c1.id = c2.id AND c2.rank = 2
            LEFT OUTER JOIN NumberedContacts AS c3
                ON c1.id = c3.id AND c3.rank = 3
            LEFT OUTER JOIN NumberedContacts AS c4
                ON c1.id = c4.id AND c4.rank = 4
            LEFT OUTER JOIN NumberedContacts AS c5
                ON c1.id = c5.id AND c5.rank = 5
        WHERE c1.rank = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82a3c/3/0)

Comment: Thank you! This looks like exactly what I need, however is there any way for me to create the view the same way you are selecting it? I need the  view to actually have the same structure as the select.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You can make a view out of any `SELECT` using `CREATE VIEW ViewName AS SELECT …`.

Comment: ah okay okay! I wasn't sure because here you have it in separate statements.

Comment: There may have been a miscommunication. The `NumberedContacts` view is just an intermediate view that is used to construct the view that you really want.